# $\dim Im \ p(T) < \dim V$ implies existence of $T$-invariant subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a vector space above $\mathbb F$, and $\dim V < \infty$.and Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ linear operator. Let $p(x) \in \mathbb F[x]$ such that $\deg p(x)=k$ and $\dim Im  \ p(T) < \dim V$. Prove that there exists a $T$-invariant subspace, $U \subseteq V$ with $0 < \dim U \leq k$ .

What can I do here?

Comment: Hint: The answer is in the question. There is really only one proper subspace mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is there anything natural about the relation of the degree of $p$ and dimension of $U$?